# Bibtex item sorting and error item missing

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm just starting with Latex and Bibtex, and now I've got a problem with the bibtex sorting. I am writing a bachelorthesis, where we have set a specific `.bst` file, the `natdin.bst`.

We have to sort the items by last name of the author/editor - that works perfectly.
But then we have some other items like technical standards - these should appear in alphanumeric order, but BEFORE alle the other items like books/articels etc.

How can I manage to do that? Do I have to change the whole bibliography-style? Or is there a way to order them manually?

And then there is another thing: I get the error `\begin{thebibliography}{27}` (or the number, how much entrys I have in my .bib-file) when I compile my latex code. Seems that there is an item missing, but I don't know why, I am using TexShop on Mac with BibDesk for the bibtex-part.

The bibliography is done in tex by:

```
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
```

which is included in an extra .sty-file, and

```
\bibliography{02__chapter/cite_bibliography}
```

in the main.tex file.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please tell us more about these "other items like technical standards." Do they have a common entry type? Do they lack author and year fields? If so, how are they cited? Separately, do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`?

Comment: The entry type is book (at least for now, and that's how it seems to be standard).
The used fields are title, publisher, year, author, address and optional keywords.

I don't use a citation management package as far as I know - where could I find that?

Comment: Please confirm: You're using the entry type `@book` for "other items like technical standards". Separately, examples of citation management packages are `natbib` and `cite`.

Comment: jep thats right. That's how they told us to do :P
Im using the management package cite

Comment: The header information in `natdin.bst` states unequivocally that this bibliography style must be used together with the `natbib` package. Note that the `cite` and `natbib` packages are mutually incompatible. I suggest you stop loading the `cite` package and start loading the `natbib` package, preferably with the options `numbers` and `square`. Be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Comment: Alright thanks, I have done that.
The problem with the \item-missing-error disappeared :)

But now to my other question: Is it possible to sort these technical standards before the other books?

Comment: How should the group of technical standards be listed: In the order they are mentioned in the document, alphabetically (by author?, by name of publication?), or in some other fashion?

Comment: They should be ordered in alphabetical/alphanumerical order, by author.
In the Author field the name of the standard is written, like "DIN9460" or "VDI2221".
Image now another book by the author name William Peters, then it should be sorted like this:
1) DIN 9460 ...
2) VDI 2221 ...
3) Peters, W. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a quick workaround, and now it works like it should. It may not be the best solution, but it fits my needs:

I defined a new command, which is empty:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{}
```

It has 3 "a"s, because thats no common Latex command and this should likely be the first alphanumeric order ever - and if its not I can change it to e.g. \aaaa or more.

In the bibliography, I write in the author field:

```
\aaa{}{DIN1234}
```

Because Bibtex orders just after the characters, this entry will be put first in the bibliography.
If I have some other entrys, I can easyly define some commands like \aab \aac etc, to put them in the correct order.